# Checking database for incorrect input

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question in regards to error handling in php. I am querying a database based on an input by the user. So basically i am checking if the user input is not found in the database I want to output "modify input" but I do not seem to get this part hence why i came to SO. Can someone help me understand how to check to see if the user input is not found? Here is a my code down below:

```
 <?php
require_once('CONFIG.php');
session_start();
 ?>
```

```
</head>

<body>
        <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

 <select name="gen" id="gen">
                <option value="">Gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>

   </select> 
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">    
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>


 <?php
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) { 
                                                                                                                                                                 ////////////  $gen = (!empty($_GET['gen']) ? trim($_GET['gen']) : '');

    try {
            $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8', $databasehost, $dbname);

  $database_handler = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
        $statement = $database_handler->prepare("
         SELECT * FROM sex WHERE type = :gen; 

            ");

    $statement->bindParam(':gen', $gen, PDO::PARAM_INT);



    $statement->execute();

if ($statememt->rowCount() > 0){


    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Gender</th>';

    echo '</tr>';
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>"; 

        echo "<td>" . $row['gen'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
    }


else   { 
 echo ' Please refine your search';

  }

     }
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
       }

   } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 `$statement->execute();`? Also is `;;` in `... = $queryResult;;` a copy/paste error here?

Comment: oh, my apologies i didn't realize that

Comment: Also, you have `... = $statement->fetchAll();` and then `... $statement->fetch()` in your loop? There is a lot of duplicate code here.

Comment: Those two statements are different and not inside my while loop.

Comment: How are they different? Also, the `->fetch()` is the while loop. They are both `$statement` so the `->fetchAll()` will fetch all the rows from `$statement` so when you do `->fetch()` on `$statement` there is nothing left to fetch. IF they are truly different, they why did you post both, and not just the one you are having issues with?

Comment: I respect your point, but what i am having issues with does not have anything to do with the fetch object. My issue is running the query and if the user enters some value which is not in the database I want to output "modify input" the rest of my code works fine.

Comment: If that is what you want to do, why then are you checking `->rowCount()` on your `->fetchAll()`, and not on your `$statement`? see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fetch the results before you use `->execute()`. Then you are trying to loop over the same result set in your while loop.

You could simplify it to something like this -

```
$statement->bindParam(':cityname', $cityname, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$statement->execute();

if ($statement->rowCount() > 0){

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>City Name</th>';

    echo '</tr>';
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $row['cityname'] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

else   { 

    echo ' modify input ';

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sean but when i run this code, it doesn't output anything from the table.

Answer (score 0):

if your queries fetching values properly then try below steps

assing `$flag=0;`
before while loop

add `$flag=1;` in while loop.

and check after while loop

```
if($flag==1){
  echo "you can show input value here as u want ".$row['cityname'];
}else{
echo ' modify input ';
}
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Okay so i edited my code to follow your explanation, but to no avail it worked. Can you tell me where i went wrong (see edited code)

Answer (score 0):

see here is complated code of your requirement.. i hope its work for you this time.

create table in test database field with name, class and gender.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
        Studnet name : <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
    </form>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    // connection with databas
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully.<br><br>";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $keyword = 'ap';
        $search_sql = "SELECT * FROM `stud` WHERE `name` LIKE :name;";
        $q = $conn->prepare($search_sql);
        $q->bindValue(':name', '%' . $_REQUEST['name'] . '%');
        $q->execute();
        $flag = 0;
        while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $flag = 1;
            $class = $r['class'];
            $gender = $r['gender'];
        }
        if ($flag == 1) {
             echo "Result :<br> Name - ".$_REQUEST['name'].",<br> Class - ".$class."<br> Gender - ".$gender;
        } else {
            echo "Record not found, Please modify Input";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please Enter name";
    }
    //close connection
    $conn = null;
}
?>
```

above code is not optimize properly. You should optimize your code. always.

try it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Still it doesn't work, I wish i could show you my full code in chat but you do not  have enough points to access the chatroom

Comment: Just try to run  code which is i provide as Ans...You only cant able to manage it logicaly.. thats it. do one think, create one file and only copy and fast my code, create table as i mention. insert dummy date.. and run code. its working. properly.

Comment: I have check ur updated code.. its same , not big deal, just try my ans code... that run properly i have tested.

Comment: No your code works, but it does not really help solve my problem. But Thanks mate